# How to start systemd user service when device is removed, and stop it when device is inserted

Tags: systemd, udev

Systemd allows starting/stopping service from udev rule using SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS environment and StopWhenUnneeded option. But, service will be started when device is inserted and stopped when device is removed. What I need is vice versa:

1. start service when device removed
2. stop service when device inserted

Since it is user service, running 'systemctl start/stop ...' from udev rule fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

udev rule for this question is

```
..., ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/bin/su USER -c 'systemctl --user stop my-service'"
..., ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/su USER -c 'systemctl --user stop my-service'"
```

The important points are:

1. Instead of `SYSTEMD_WANTS`/`SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS`, service should be start/stop using systemctl since start/stop does not match device add/remove.
2. To start/stop service from other user `su` + `systemctl --user` is used.
3. Program pass to `RUN` udev key should be either from `/usr/lib/udev` or absolute pass must be used (`man udev`).